# EF code-first many-to-many with additional data

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [EDR_SECURITY].[Person](
    [ixPerson] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [EDR_SECURITY].[SecurityGroup](
    [ixSecurityGroup] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [sDescription] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [EDR_SECURITY].[PersonSecurityGroupDefinition](
    [ixPerson] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ixSecurityGroup] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [fPrivilege] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PersonSecurityGroupDefinition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ixPerson] ASC,
    [ixSecurityGroup] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How do I create in EF code-first the relationships between `Person` and `Security Group`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood exactly from the raw SQL...

EDIT: and as suggested in your specific case I think this is pretty close at least...

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonSecurityGroupDefinition> 
        PersonSecurityGroups { get; set; }
}
public class SecurityGroup
{
    public int SecurityGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonSecurityGroupDefinition> 
        PersonSecurityGroups { get; set; }
}
public class PersonSecurityGroupDefinition
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int SecurityGroupID { get; set; }
    public int Privilege { get; set; }
    // don't use virtual here as these are PK-s
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public SecurityGroup SecurityGroup { get; set; }
}
```

...and in the `OnModelCreating` (override in your `DbContext`...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSecurityGroupDefinition>()
    .HasKey(i => new { i.PersonID, i.SecurityGroupID });

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSecurityGroupDefinition>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Person)
    .WithMany(u => u.PersonSecurityGroups)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.PersonID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonSecurityGroupDefinition>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.SecurityGroup)
    .WithMany(d => d.PersonSecurityGroups)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.SecurityGroupID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...hope this is it.

Comment: me too, look closely - this is the index table, it's many-to-many - you just need to replace the User w/ Person, Role with SecurityGroup and your PersonSecurityGroupDefinition is UserRole.

Comment: You really could have spent the additional minute to replace the class and property names with the names from the question and show how the other two entities would look like. You know the complete answer and it just feels a bit lazy to copy and paste another model into the answer and say "here, this is very similar".

Comment: +1: Good answer :) I don't understand though why the nav. properties in the join entity shouldn't be `virtual`, they represent normal FK relationships. That the FK is part of the PK at the same time doesn't matter imo. I would also remove the `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` because a join table usually has cascading delete. There won't be a "multiple cascading delete path" exception because the two cascading deletes are from different tables.

Comment: @Slauma point taken on the edit :) - edited - I just had no time and I feel like a good pointer gets people 'involved' more. Nevertheless you're right and on SO it seems to be a predominant way of answering (thorough answers).

Comment: @Slauma I had problems in that very same case if FK-s that are PK-s (or corresponding navigation properties) are marked as virtual - with some strange error (don't remember, seemingly all is right but insert fails) - it may be just with Sql CE provider or in more complex cases (e.g. withMany() empty etc.). Frankly not sure, will try to nail that down with some details when I manage, I just remember that was the required thing and since then I'm keeping those two things together.

Comment: This specially useful when it references itself, e.g. a Manager (Person) that supervise others and also could be supervised. such as `List<Person> SupervisedBy`, and `List<Person> SupervisorOf`