# Entity Framework Model First - 1 to 1..0 relationship - Why it does not like foreign keys which are not primary?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to model the following :

A Picture has many types so I made a relationship table between Pictures and Types.

I want to know how many types an image has so I need a primary key identifying the relationship.

Types 1 to 1..0 Relationship * to 1 Pictures

I want relationship to have as foreign key the id of the picture and also the id of the type, and also to identify that relationship.

It says : "Multiplicity is not valid in role "..." Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *"

I am working with EF 5 in VS2012

Is there any way to hard code this? I have many 1 to 1..0 relationships in my model...

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

I must say I don't understand everything you're trying to say,

...but I'm guessing you you want a `many-to-many relation in between Types and Pictures` with a custom info attached to the 'relationship'.

Take a look at the post I made here, just replace `Person` with `Picture`, `SecurityGroup` with `Type`. And you 'relationship' entity is `PersonSecurityGroupDefinition`.

[EF code-first many-to-many with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199158/ef-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-data/10199455#10199455)

You don't need a `pk` on your 'relationship table'. That's done by using a composite key of both (and you can always find it that way).

You then add additional that for each 'relationship' - like I put in there the `public int Privilege { get; set; }`.